How to set the width of MUI TextField to match special number of characters?
I have multiple MUI TextField objects in a from. I have defined different max length for each TextField. I know that "width" property of TextField sets the width of input box, but how can I set different sizes(in pixel) for TextField input box based on this max length number( which is in character)? ( I mean how can I convert max length of characters to pixel to pass it to "width" property?)
For example TextField-1 can accept only 10 characters and TextField-2 can accept 500 characters. I want the input box of TextField-2 to be longer than TextField-1 and in accordance with 500 characters.
